# Twilio Flex dual transcribe (VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription)

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I need to implement dual call recording in FLEX.

Please tell me how to implement dual recording and enable transcription for twilio flex?

I did it with this instruction, but transcription doesn't work because Add-ons VoiceBase does not support *StartCallRecordingAPI*.

[Link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/insights/enable-dual-channel-recordings)

I tried to do it via <Dial> but that didn't help either

Comment: What do you mean when you say it didn't work? Installing an add-on should just add the results from the add-on into the webhook to your callback. What are you experiencing and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hello, @philnash
The fact is that the "VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription" is used for source:
Record Verb Recordings,
Outgoing Call (API) Recordings,
Conference Recordings,
Dial Verb Recordings.
But it doesn't work on Source === Start Call Recording API.

Comment: So when you start a recording with the API you don’t get a transcription? This sounds like something you should contact [Twilio support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us) about.

Comment: @philnash Yes, absolutely right. I am not getting a transcription because "VoiceBase High Accuracy Transcription" for some reason does not process "Source" === "StartCallRecordingAPI"

Comment: You said you tried it by `<Dial>` too, but that didn't help? Overall, you might need to either contact support to get that fixed, or use the recordingStatusCallback webhook to take the recording URL and send the recording to VoiceBase from your own application.

Comment: I don't fully understand how <Dial> works, do I understand correctly that <Dial> redirects a call to another number. I.e. do I need to have at least 2 numbers to record?

Comment: What might be useful is if you take a step back and explain what you need to do with your call and I'll see what I can suggest.

Comment: I agree with you. I need a transcription of incoming calls in Twilio Flex. I want the record to be double (dual record). This is necessary so that the transcription is also double. (Speaker 1, Speaker2)

I need a double transcription of incoming calls in Twilio Flex